# Is is possible to perform operations on a Sharepoint server file store from an external server?

Tags: php, sharepoint

I need to organise a bunch of files being stored on a Sharepoint server. I have a login to Sharepoint and privileges to modify files, but no access to any scripting or admin settings. The quickest way to make these changes currently is to "Open with windows explorer" - some kind of windows file server thingy, and that's **very slow**.

I want to know if it is possible to send requests, to make changes to the file structure, from an external server, preferably in PHP, but anything will do.

I need to be able to:

- Get the details of the files in a folder
- Create a folder
- Move a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the [SharePoint Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878586%28office.12%29.aspx) could help you!
Take a look at the [Lists Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists%28office.12%29.aspx), its methods should provide what you need to do.

Comment: It looks like the Document Workspace Service and Copy Service are the right ones: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774834(v=office.12).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/copy(v=office.12).aspx

Do these look right?